# Changing an object size/rotation doesn't update information in Transform window

Tags: objects, transforms

I have downloaded an object file from the internet. The object imports fine except for when I try to change the scale/rotation of the object. I do not see the Transform window information update when I make a change.
Below rotation not being updated in in the Transformation Panel.

[image: Changing Rotation Example]

Comment: The outline should be yellow in order to transform the active (context) object. Not sure how something like this can happen. Is there a second object in selection?

Comment: You are right, there is a second object which is selected, otherwise the dot would be yellow, not orange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This situation can occur if you select 2 objects, and then hide the last selected one.
With the last selected object hidden the rotation will center around the only available one now and it looks exactly like this.

Here the procedure to get to the same situation:

[image: hidden objects info shown while other object is being transformed]

**Solution:** Make sure the object you work on is the active selected one, yellow outline.